# Anti-symmetric and non-singular matrix

Tags: matrices

$A$ is an anti-symmetric matrix and S is a symmetric matrix, such that the matrices $I+AS$ is non-sigular if

$B=(I-AS)(I+AS)^{-1}$

Prove that $B^{T}SB=S$

$B^TSB=[(I-AS)(I+AS)^{-1}]^{T}S[(I-AS)(I+AS)^{-1}]$

$B^TSB=[(I+AS)^{-T}(I-AS)^T]S[(I-AS)(I+AS)^{-1}]$

$B^TSB=[(I+AS)^{-T}(I-AS)^T](S-SAS)(I+AS)^{-1}]$

$B^TSB=[(I+S^TA^T)^{-1}(I-S^TA^T)(I-SA)S(I+AS)^{-1}]$

Since S is symmetric, $S^{T}=S$

A is anti-symmetric, $A^T=-A$

$B^TSB=[(I-SA)^{-1}(I+SA)(I-SA)S(I+AS)^{-1}]$

Since $(I+SA)(I-SA)$ are commutative,

$B^TSB=[(I-SA)^{-1}(I-SA)(I+SA)S(I+AS)^{-1}]$

$B^TSB=(I+SA)S(I+AS)^{-1}$

$B^TSB=(S+SAS)(I+AS)^{-1}$

$B^TSB=S(I+AS)(I+AS)^{-1}$

$B^TSB=S$

Answer (score 1):

$$B^TSB=(I+AS)^{-T}(I-AS)^TS(I-AS)(I+AS)^{-1}
=(I-SA)^{-1}(I+SA)S(I-AS)(I+AS)^{-1}
=(I-SA)^{-1}S(I+AS)(I-AS)(I+AS)^{-1}
=(I-SA)^{-1}S(I-AS)(I+AS)(I+AS)^{-1}
=(I-SA)^{-1}S(I-AS)
=(I-SA)^{-1}(I-SA)S=S.
$$